# Pyspark foreachPartition not writing all data

Tags: json, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand how foreachPartition works. Since foreachPartition print statements don't get sent back to my Spark driver stdout from the executors, I thought of writing data to S3 instead.

So I created a random dataframe and tried to write JSON data from each partition to s3. However, I noticed that some of the data doesn't get written to s3. No matter how many partitions (2 or 18 or 38, etc...) I choose for my dataframe ('df_2.rdd.getNumPartitions()' in this example), there seems to be some data that doesn't appear in s3 every time. How can i get foreachPartitions to write my entire dataframe to s3? What am I doing wrong here?

```
#Creating random dataframe filled with random numbers
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,5], [22,55,112],[151,663,4123],[6634,31,23],[2141,22,22],[21,11,2],[66,85,4]])
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
df_2 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df)
df_2.show(10)
print('partitions: ', df_2.rdd.getNumPartitions())
#output:
```

> ```
> +----+---+----+
> |   0|  1|   2|
> +----+---+----+
> |   1|  2|   5|
> |  22| 55| 112|
> | 151|663|4123|
> |6634| 31|  23|
> |2141| 22|  22|
> |  21| 11|   2|
> |  66| 85|   4|
> +----+---+----+
>
> partitions:  2
> ```

```
import random
import os
import json
import boto3
#function to pass in foreachParittion
my_bucket = 'ramdom_bucket'
folder = 'my/random/folder'

def f(iterator):
    #assigning random number for a file
    rand_int = random.randint(4,512314123)
#     rand_int = 512
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3object = s3.Object(my_bucket, os.path.join(folder, 'data_{}.json'.format(rand_int)))
    #creating list from partition
    ls_iter = list(iterator)
    #Copying list object as JSON to a random file name in s3
    s3object.put(
        Body=(bytes(json.dumps(ls_iter).encode('UTF-8')))
    )
#df_2 is the dataframe I created in previous code block
df_2.foreachPartition(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my view ,do you want to know how the Spark compute internally? You can get something useful from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html. It will give you a general perspective to feel the Scheduler of Spark. And more, you can go to the Scheduler, Stage Scheduler, Task Scheduler to learn how the Job to be executed.

And to this question, I think the H=high concurrency and high computing speed leave little time for S3 to store the Object.

```
//ADD RETURN RESULT FOR PUT ACTION, And you can debug the error.
```

`s3object.put( Body=(bytes(json.dumps(ls_iter).encode('UTF-8'))) )`

```
//ADD SOME TIME TO WAIT UNTIL THE PUT ACTION FINISGED;
```

Comment: I added time.sleep(15) after the PUT ACTION, and some data are still missing.

Comment: Try to write date into the log? Could this program run normally in the mode of Local?

Comment: How would I write data to logs in this case? Each partition may be on a different executor. It's the same reason print statements don't work as I had mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure that all executor can connect  your s3?

Comment: The connections to S3 may be closed by S3 because of more actions.